# Proper way for if and else if conditional statement using same function

Tags: php

I got the following PHP code:

```
if ($_POST['type'] == 'A') {
   callfunction();
} elseif ($_POST['type'] == 'B'){
    callfunction();
}
```

both condition calls the same function callfunction(); is there any proper way to do this? Or shoul my logic be okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the OR operator `||`

```
if ($_POST['type'] == 'A' || $_POST['type'] == 'B') {
   callfunction();
}
```

Comment: Nice, thank you sir. will accept this later as it says i can accept after 6mins.